# Combine Bash Regex Expressions

Tags: regex, bash

I have a server that has some pages written in [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). I have a `launch.sh` script that essentially builds all the CSS files from LESS, puts them in a directory, and starts the server (written in Node.js).

Here is what the script looks like currently:

```
# Searches the CSS directory for LESS files
for file in views/less/*.less
do
    FROM=$file
    A=${file/.*/.css}
    B=${A/less/css}
    TO=${B/views/resources}
    echo "$FROM -> $TO"
    # Compiles each LESS file into a CSS file of the same name with minified output
    lessc --clean-css $FROM $TO
done
```

Everything works fine, but I was wondering if I could condense the regex expressins, denoated as `A` and `B`. Essentially the script takes the entire build path, let's say:

```
/views/less/style.less
```

and replaces `less` to `css` and replaces `views` to `resources`. So, the final path (after the conversion process) becomes:

```
/resources/css/style.css
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the code would become way less readable. To me, now it looks clear and concise.

Comment: I would reuse the same variable (instead of A, B & TO, just: TO), but apart from that, it's clear.

Comment: These are not regular expressions, they are glob patterns. [shell parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) do not nest, so you have no choice but to do one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all occurrences of `less` in a variable by doubling the slash:

```
A=${file//less/css}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I want to replace `less` to `css` and replace `views` to `resources`, not all instances of `less`.